# Create inactive account

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to synchronize with another system, accounts, and if the entity is inactive in that system, I want to create the account with inactive status. something very simple like:

```
{       
    "accountnumber": "InactiveAcct",
    "name": "Account that should be created as inactive",
    "description": "demo",
    
    "statecode": 1,
    "statuscode": 2
}
```

I'm doing a POST request but as a reply I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "0x80048408",
        "message": "2 is not a valid status code for state code AccountState.Active on account with Id e2d0f844-313e-eb11-a813-000d3a795762."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot create (POST) an inactive record, you have to create it first and then make an update (PATCH) call to mark inactive. This is by design and it’s a limitation. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/312831/problem-creating-inactive-record-of-a-custom-entity/908076)

> statecode field is not available for create. Record will be always created as active. The only way for you is to do 2 steps operation - create and set as inactive after.

In other words, `statecode=0` is set as default by system, when you pass `statuscode=2` in create payload - the platform validation kicks in and say this is invalid pair.

Comment: Thank you @Arun Vinoth, I suspected that could be a limitation because I tried to create and then just a patch to update status and that was working. Is there a logic reason for this ? Best regards,